Inferring the specific overload of a function passed as a parameter to a generic function
In the below example, awaitCallback takes a function as its first argument, where that function's last parameter is a callback. The remainder of the arguments are the arguments to func, excluding the last argument (the callback). The idea is that the awaitCallback function will return a Promise that is resolved inside the callback, so it should not be allowed as an argument.
This works great except for the case of overloaded functions. Ideally, typescript would infer the correct overload of func based on the arguments provided to args. If I explicitly provide the type arguments to awaitCallback, then everything works fine. It seems to me that TypeScript should see Args and automatically select the overload of func that satisfies the constraints. Is this possible?
type NodeCallback<R> = (err: (Error | null) | R, matches?: R | undefined) => void;

type Func<Args extends unknown[], LA, R> = (...args: [...Args, LA]) => R;

export function awaitCallback<Args extends unknown[], LA>(func: Func<Args, NodeCallback<LA>, void>, ...args: Args): Promise<LA> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const callback: NodeCallback<LA> = (err, result) => {
            if (result !== undefined)
                resolve(result);
            else if (err instanceof Error)
                reject(err);
            else if (err !== null)
                resolve(err);
            else
                reject(new Error('Unknown error'));
        };

        func(...args, callback);
    });
};

declare function test(arg1: string, arg2: number, callback: (err: Error | null, matches: string[]) => void): void;

declare function test2(arg1: string, callback: (err: Error | null, matches: string[]) => void): void;
declare function test2(arg1: string, arg2: number | undefined, callback: (err: Error | null, matches: number[]) => void): void;

// no overloads, no problem
const res = awaitCallback(test, 'test', 3);
//    ^?

// works if i explicity provide type arguments
const res2 = awaitCallback<[string], string[]>(test2, 'test');
//    ^?

// won't infer a less specific overload
const res3 = awaitCallback(test2, 'test');
//    ^?

// works fine for the most-specific overload
const res4 = awaitCallback(test2, 'test', 3);
//    ^?



Playground

it's a design limitation of TS; see ms/TS#35501 and the linked q/a above.

Thank you, you're a TypeScript legend. I figured it was likely a limitation, but I was hoping there was a way to trick the compiler into rejecting the other overloads.
